# How can I make a column filed readOnly after create?

Tags: ignite-ui, iggrid

I want to make a row field readOnly after the row of the grid was created. I want to make it work  both in editMode 'row' and 'rowedittemplate'. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the column settings in the updating feature and set readOnly to true for the updating of the column you want to be non-editable:

```
$(element).igGrid({
    features: [
        {
            name: "Updating",
            columnSettings: [
                { columnKey: "Key", readOnly: true }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

[Here's the API docs.](http://help.infragistics.com/jQuery/2014.1/ui.iggridupdating#options:columnSettings.readOnly)

Comment: Thanks. Now I see that I did not understand the column settings api right. I thought that igGrid.columnSettings is the only way and the others in the separate features are just redundant ways to do it.

Comment: @OgnyanDimitrov Hey :) The columnSettings are specific for each feature, so yes they are not redundant!